# What statistical tests should i use if both normality and homogenity of distribution assumptions were violated?

Tags: normal-distribution, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

my (quantitative) data are divided into 4 groups:

T0, n = 415

T1, n = 93

T2, n = 74

T3, n = 51

***NOTICE THE DIFFERENT GROUP SIZES!**

I wish to compare between the groups.
Usually ANOVA would fit, however, two assumptions are violated:

1. **"Normal distribution" is violated**
2. **"Homogeneous distribution" is violated**

**More info:**

**1. Homogeneous distribution:**

Based on the robvar command in STATA these are the results:

W0  =  4.8178100   df(3, 629)     Pr > F = 0.00252256

W50 =  3.0713811   df(3, 629)     Pr > F = 0.02730491

W10 =  3.6291696   df(3, 629)     Pr > F = 0.01284074

**2. Normal distribution:**

Shapiro-Wilk W test:

W = 0.928

V = 29.833

z = 8.248

Prob>z = .000

Shapiro-Francia W' test:

W = 0.935

V = 29.071

z = 7.505

Prob>z = .000

*Of note, the non-normal shapes are very similar for all four groups.

**3. My hypothesis is about differences in means.**

What should i do?

What test should i use?

What post-hoc test would best fit this test?

Comment: Answer may depend on how badly the normality assumption is violated and whether non-sormal shapes are similar for all four.. Can you show data summaries and plots? Procedure `oneway.test` in R does not require equal group variances.

Comment: I've added some information to the question

Comment: It would be nice to see probability plots of both groups, but so far there's little here to be concerned about.

Comment: This will depend on what you want (point estimates, well-behaved p-values and CIs) and how flexible you are willing to be about exactly what you are comparing (arithmetic means, geometric means, medians, location more generally).

Comment: If your hypothesis is definitely about differences in (arithmetic) means, that would rule out some obvious suggestions here, such as Kruskal-Wallis (which for the similar shapes across the groups you note would be an approximate test for differences in medians, with Dunn's test for the post-hoc comparisons--since you're using Stata [note the capitalisation, it's not an abbreviation], "net search dunntest" would find a user-written program for this).

Comment: Transformations will change the question, e.g. a log transformation will make this a comparison of geometric means. If the departures from normality and homoscedasticity of residuals are concerning and you really want to explore differences in (arithmetic) means, bootstrapping would be the obvious suggestion to me assuming you want the trinity of effect size, 95% CI, and p-value for interpretation and reporting.

Comment: The first thing to do when analysing data is to look at it in graphical form. Try plotting all of the points, box plots, and histograms. After inspecting the data that way you will have a MUCH more clear impression of its properties than the statistical summaries that you have given can provide. Then you might be able to decide whether to look for a robust test or a normalising transformation (logarithms very often work).

Comment: What is your response variable? E.g. is it a duration of time, a count, a measurement of a physical dimension?